# Retain Flink Checkpoint on cancellation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-checkpoint

I'm using Flink 1.15.0 and I want to keep triggered checkpoint when job is cancelled.

Flink indicates to set ExternalizeCheckpointCleanup mode in this way

```
env.getCheckpointConfig().setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(
    CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

From Javadoc they say:

> ```
> The target directory for externalized checkpoints is configured via CheckpointingOptions.CHECKPOINTS_DIRECTORY.
> ```

So I wrote this line:

```
config.set(CheckpointingOptions.CHECKPOINTS_DIRECTORY, "hdfs:///checkpoints-data");
```

But in their documentation, they show this snippet:

```
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("hdfs:///checkpoints-data/");
```

What is the difference between checkpoint directory and checkpoint storage?

Comment: I don't believe there's any difference. (But I think you need three slashes, as in "hdfs:///checkpoints-data/").

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson. I fixed it, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The same. You can `setCheckpointStorage()` directly in your application, or Flink will use the `CheckpointingOptions.CHECKPOINTS_DIRECTORY` to create a checkpoint storage.